# Deriving sample size using Hoeffding's Inequality

Tags: probability, statistics

I want to use Hoeffding's Inequality to determine the necessary sample size $n$ to construct a confidence interval of $\epsilon$ and $\alpha$.

I've consulted the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality#Confidence_Intervals) and am confused as to the use of $log(\alpha/2)$ in the derived sample size inequality, shouldn't it be a $ln(\alpha/2)$? Or this there something I'm missing that makes it a base 10 logarithm as opposed to natural?

Comment: Logarithm with base $e$ is often denoted $\log$ by mathematicians.

Comment: To many people, $\log$ means log to the base $e$.  The notation $\ln$ only became popular relatively recently.